# PHP date_diff function returns wrong result

Tags: php, date, datediff

I was trying to find the number of months between two dates using `date_diff()` in PHP. As we all know the number of months between 2019-03-01 and 2020-01-31 is 11 months, but the following code return 10 months.

```
$date1=date_create("2019-03-01");
$date2=date_create("2020-01-31");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%m months");
```

**Output**

```
10 months
```

Why this code return 1 month less?

Comment: Likely because the actual duration is 10 months and 30 days, but you're only displaying the "month" portion. `echo $diff->format("%m months %d days");`

Comment: but why it return like this?

Comment: Because it's not a full 11 months.

Comment: 2020-01-31 is treated as 2020-01-31 00:00:00 and 2019-03-01 as 2019-03-01 00:00:00 . is this the reason?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the difference in months from the beginning of the first day to the end of the last day at midnight, you can also set the end date to midnight (24h !) or add a day.

```
<?php
$dateStart = date_create("2019-03-01");
$dateEnd = date_create("2020-01-31");

//set Time to midnight or add a day
$dateEnd->setTime(24,0,0);

$diff = date_diff($dateStart,$dateEnd);
echo $diff->format("%m months");
//11 months
```

[try self.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/628a2df071253cd47f0aa39d54e4797a57976988)

Comment: Yes! I was trying to get days difference and using date('now') vs a set date and did not realise at first the amount of hours was changing the day value, makes sense! I used "new DateTime('now')->setTime(0, 0)"

Answer (score 2):

The difference is 10 months and 30 days, which is what `date_diff()` returns:

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (16) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(10)
  ["d"]=>
  int(30)
  ["h"]=>
  int(0)
  ["i"]=>
  int(0)
  ["s"]=>
  int(0)
  ["f"]=>
  float(0)
  ["weekday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday_behavior"]=>
  int(0)
  ["first_last_day_of"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)
  ["days"]=>
  int(336)
  ["special_type"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_amount"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_weekday_relative"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_special_relative"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

ETA as @showdev commented above.